# convert a numeric into matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a expression which is when I type class numeric but it looks like this

```
A      B     C     D      E    F
1.2    1.1   1.05  1.4   1.2   1.1
```

the object is called e and

```
dim(e)
NULL
```

is there some way to change the format of the initial object e so that it is also subsettable

Thanks,

Comment: You might be looking for the `length()` function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear, but I think your `e` is just a vector with names, like:

```
e <- setNames(c(1.2,1.1,1.05,1.4,1.2,1.1),LETTERS[1:6])
dput(e)
#structure(c(1.2, 1.1, 1.05, 1.4, 1.2, 1.1), .Names = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
dim(e)
#NULL
```

You can subset such an object like you would any other vector:

```
e[1:3]
#   A    B    C 
#1.20 1.10 1.05
```

...including using the names assigned to each value:

```
e["A"]
#  A 
#1.2
```